# Git: How to remove secondary remote repo

Tags: git, git-remote

I had set up a 2nd remote repository by running this command

```
git remote set-url origin --push --add <another remote>
```

When I do a `git remote -v`

```
origin  https://url1.com/a.git (fetch)
origin  https://url2.com/a.git (push)
```

How can I remove one of the remote repo?

Looking at `git remote --help`, I see that I can do

`git remote remove origin`, but would that remove both of them?

What's the best practice to have multiple remote URLs? Should I have set different branch names instead of having 2 `origins`?

Comment: I see only one remote there, `origin`. It just uses two URLs, one for fetching and one for pushing. This is common for PR / code review tools like gerrit. Do you want to set the push URL back to the same as the fetch URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your situation has only one remote, `origin`. To change the push value of the remote, without adding a new value, use `git remote set-url` without `--add`. To be extra-explicit, you can also specify the URL that you want to replace:

```
git remote set-url origin --push https://url1.com/a.git https://url2.com/a.git
```

This replaces your updated url2 with your original url1.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a 2nd (or more) remote repository by `remote add`. sample:

```
git remote add myOrigin1 url1
git remote add myOrigin2 url2
.
.
.
```

then you can remove remote by:

```
git remote remove myOrigin1
git remote remove myOrigin2
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have one remote, what happens is that Git by default sets up separately the url for `push` and `fetch`. You can leave this as is.